# HTTPS image request turns into an HTTP request in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, subdomain

I have a subdomain static.vivicheruti.com that points to vivicheruti.com/static.

I'm using Wordpress 5.2.1

I have a test page where I wrote this tag:

```
<img src="https://static.vivicheruti.com/Nube.png">
```

When I access the page, the image doesn´t show AND I get this "error"

**Mixed Content: The page at 'https://vivicheruti.com/prueba/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://vivicheruti.com/static/Nube.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.**

The URL is resolved OK but why the HTTP?

So I host my site on Siteground. I asked for help there but they say this is a Wordpress developer issue...

this https to http only happens in this case and I don´t know who is resolving this.

Any clues? Pls just ask for any extra information you need.

I have Cloudflare as part por Siteground's plan.

*Updated --> FIXED (.htaccess)*

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=vivicheruti.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://vivicheruti.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it said http instead of https in the last rule.

Comment: If you pay attention to the message you'll notice that the URL of the image has changed as well: `https://static.vivicheruti.com/Nube.png` vs `http://vivicheruti.com/static/Nube.png`. Something on your site (an .htaccess rule? A plugin?) is redirecting requests to `https://static.vivicheruti.com/*` to `http://vivicheruti.com/static/*` so double check your configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I double checked in my .htaccess huge file and found an "http" redirection. Hadn´t seen it.

Comment: Don't mention it. You can post your own answer and mark it as accepted if you wish :)